# Series where only every 3rd term is non-zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

(sorry for my poor English)
As a part of a bigger assigment I'm trying to write a series where only every 3rd term is non-zero

$0,0,a,0,0,a,0,0,a,\ldots$ and so on were $a$ is an integer.

What could be the rule for such a series?

Thank you!

Comment: I seems you are asking about a sequence. correct?

Answer (score 1):

Define$$a_n=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if $n$ is not a multiple of }3\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle x_n=\frac{a}{3}\left[1+\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^n\right]$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} $ we have $ \omega^2+\omega+1=0 $ then 
$$ a_n=\frac{1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}}{3}a $$
works fine

Answer (score 0):

Or generating function:

$$g(x)= \frac{a x^2}{1-x^3}$$
series at point $x=0$

$$a x^2+a x^5+a
   x^8+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\frac a2(1+(-1)^{n^2\mod3})$$